# Multiple web apps security demystification

Tags: security, spring-security, birt, jboss7.x

I am deploying two web apps on a single jboss as7 instance.  One app is spring/maven based and uses spring security for authentication.  The other app is a birt web app that doesn't require direct login authentication.  The two apps are joined by a single menu link that is only displayed when the logged in user possesses a management role.  So the spring app is the main app and it provides a link to a birt web app, if the user is a manager.  My problem is that the spring app is secure (no direct url access, user required to login, etc) but the birt app can be accessed without logging in if someone is aware of the app's url.  I don't want to have two separate login pages.  I want the spring app authentication to also determine access to the birt app, but I'm not clear on how to do this.  I added a security constraint to my birt app's web.xml file and a jboss-web.xml file to establish the security domain for the app.  The security constraint does not make a difference whether it's there or not, but the security domain does restrict access to the birt app via url.  So what is the next step from here?  How do I grab the authentication from the spring app (jsessionid?) and use it to permit a user access to the security domain that contains the birt app?

Both apps are on the same domain...e.g "domain/springApp or domain/birtApp" if anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here too, since birt.war is altogether a separate webapp .. it has its own session, so anyone knows ur birt.war name & report name via url, they can not only run the reports without authentication but can also download ur reports which is again a security issue(here download reports means .rptdesign files in which they can see ur queries).

possible solutions are :-

1> Integrate BIRT report engine 3.7 in ur webapp, & use servlets to generate reports html pages then show that in ur application. in this, drawback is that it creates html files for each report u run & will not get the web viewers ajax functionality & export functionality like excel,pdf etc.

2> This doesn't work for me but u can give it a try. Integrating BIRT 3.7 web viewer in ur webapp. i did this & was able to display web viewer in my webapp but this link was also working : report=report1.rptdesign">http://localhost:7110/myapp/frameset?_report=report1.rptdesign

i thought that it will redirect this link to my webapp login page as it does for any other pages in my webapp but i got a big NO. Cause was separate sessions.

Conclusion was to extract web viewer from birt & modify it to connect with the my webapp which is like creating birt again.

Oh!! here is the link for birt 3.7 integration : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Birt_3.7_Migration_Guide

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I solved the problem by integrating the birt app into my spring app.  It's strange though; I'm able to run the integrated app on jetty with no problem, but I get an exception when I run the report on jboss as 7.  The exception occurs when I attempt to run the report.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to protect the birt web application via spring security (so another spring security configuration is required in the birt app). The spring security filters in the birt app would inspect the UserDetails object from the incoming session to determine if a user is authorized to access the birt web app.

Spring security -> app1 -> spring security -> birt app

This is a fairly big discussion for a stack overflow answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  If I understand what you are suggesting correctly, then I should establish spring security in the birt app and connect app1 to the birt app through spring security.  I can try this, but I don't really understand where to start.  Is there a tutorial related to this?  BTW, the scope of the discussion doesn't compare to the size of the headache this issue is giving me ;)  I need all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Choose your jboss sso](http://java.dzone.com/articles/choosing-sso-your-jboss) and the use of tomcat valves.

That could be of help.

Regards